# How to find previous questions

Tags: support, profile-page

How to find my entire question and its answers? I can see only few that are recent. Thanks!

I have tried viewing in my profile but can find only recent questions.

Comment: There's a "view more" link underneath

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3067524/user3067524?tab=questions

Comment: I tried but still only few questions.Thanks!

Comment: @user3067524 It doesn't show deleted questions, if that's what you were expecting.

Comment: It is showing me only since December 7th. I am sure I have been using this site for a long time and i must have more questions.

Comment: Oh...really ??? why it is deleted ??

Comment: I have very valuable questions and answers tha ti can use for my future projects. It will be a big loss for me if i lose some. I spent lots of time for geting answers.

Comment: Question needs to fit the Q&A format and be valid according to the Help Center. Usually, when they are deleted, there is a very good reason for it.

Comment: Your profile says you registered on December 4. Perhaps you have another account, or were using the site anonymously (possibly from a different machine)?

Comment: No it's showing since December 4, there is a bug in the questions tab that show the time of last activity instead of time asked. This is the first question you asked with this account that is not deleted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385256/span-submit-button-to-col-xs-12

Comment: Yeah i remeber stackoverflow forced me to use yahoo or gmail account to login.Is there anyway to find what id i have used before?

Comment: @user3067524 you can't answer questions without a registered account. If you used the same email address in your old account try filling [this form](http://stackoverflow.com/contact), choose "Other" and explain what you want.

Comment: Luckly I have bookmarked one the question I have asked in October,2013 and was able to find the profile and all the questions. I did not lose anything :) http://stackoverflow.com/users/2088016/user2088016?tab=questions&sort=votes

Comment: It's not a good idea to work with two accounts unless you have good reason for that. Please ask the team to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your profile, and where you see the recent activity, click on the link that shows "x Answers"  or "y Questions" 
[image: Freehand circles]

Alternatively, you can go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3067524/user3067524?tab=questions) for questions or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3067524/user3067524?tab=answers) for answers